# Undoing a duplicate super close vote

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, dupehammer

I just closed this question [C# String reference not set to an instance of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731574/c-sharp-string-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-a-string) as a duplicate and realised after that it wasn't quite a duplicate. I suspect the answer will be useful since the problem is due to a user having a null that they can't find but its an `ArgumentNullException` rather than a `NullReferenceException`.

I can't undo my vote any more because it instantly closed it.

What are my options now?

Is there a quick and easy way to undo my mistake or do I have to vote to reopen and wait for several others to also vote to reopen?

NB. I have looked for a more suitable answer to have it consider a duplicate of but can't find one in a quick search.

Comment: Is there a more appropriate duplicate you could use to close or none at all?

Comment: As you duped by hammer (gold bage in tag) you can also single side reopen. I do think you can also edit the duplicates list, so you may just add another reference if someone add it as comment.

Comment: If you can close a question with the dupehammer, you can reopen it too. You won't have to wait for other votes.

Comment: What @SebastianProske probably refers to is that you can edit your duplicate link, and replace with the appropriate one.

Comment: Oooh... I didn't know I had a super reopen to cancel out my super close! Will that wipe out the close votes that were already there or will they still be there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they'll be gone.

Comment: @Chris _"Will that wipe out the close votes that were already there or will they still be there?"_ It will remove the former close votes.

Comment: Also remember if you reopen, you won't be able to close it again.

Comment: There are no "close votes that were already there". The question is *closed*. There are no pending votes. Just as you can cast a binding vote to close, you can cast a binding vote to reopen. Once each time.

Comment: @SebastianProske: As mentioned in my footnote I couldn't find a better answer. The more I think about it the more I am wondering if it was correct - the original question was about a null argument exception but for the most part the ways to find it and fix it are the same as for a NRE. The bottom line in the top answered question for the dupe target is completely valid. It just happens that the exception type was different...

Comment: Thanks for the comments all - still relatively new to this privilege and still trying to understand it all properly.

Comment: Also I just noticed I got a downvote - I don't tend to frequent meta that much - did I do something wrong in asking this question?

Comment: I just recently got a gold badge for PHP, and after some awkwardness with the dupe hammer, I've been much more cautious about voting to close as duplicate. It made me realize, I think I've been using my close votes somewhat incorrectly all along. It's easier to treat them like duplicate "suggestions" when you don't have a binding close vote, but you really should be certain it's a duplicate before you vote, whether you have a gold badge or not.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: Yeah. In this case I foolishly believed the OP when they said "i'm getting this null reference exception" - lesson learned - never believe what anybody says. ;-)

Comment: This really doesn't matter.  It's the same answer whether it was a NRE or a NAE.  The problem is that *something is null that OP doesn't think is null*. The solution is **to debug your code** and figure out *what* is null.  Then you can either figure out how to handle a null there better, and if that fails, *then* ask your question as to how it should be handled.  That's fully covered in the NRE close target. If anything, it suggests that the dupe target should be altered to include references to ANE being a very closely related issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As a gold badge holder you have a binding dupe close privilege for question tagged with a tag you have a gold badge in.  This means no matter what votes are on the question your duplicate close vote will instantly close the question and apply the duplicate as the closure reason.  All the others that voted to close will also show up as they voted to close, even if it was for a different reason.

On the flip side you also have a binding reopen vote for duplicates.  This will instantly reopen the question.  At that point the question will have no close votes on it as they were applied when the question was closed.

Now, if you realized the question is a dupe, but you used the wrong target, you can actually edit the duplicate list.  This allows you to change the target without having to reopen the question.  If the question is not actually a dupe at all your only recourse is to reopen it and hope that it gets closed for the correct reason (if it needs to be closed).

Comment: Worth mentioning that after closing and reopening, you can no longer cast close votes on it.  related: if you vote to close for some reason other than duplicate, you can't dup-hammer once the OP edits the question, because you've already used your once CV per question. :(

Comment: @PeterCordes one of the reasons why I don't vote as too broad unless I'm positive that the question is trash.